# What is the problem with this line of code in my pandas library?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am going to use the pandas library in python to get a csv file from the user and perform various actions on it, but unfortunately I encounter an error

My setup and file locations:
[image: The code]

The error message:
[image: The Error]

The code that causes the error:

```python
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv('Desctop\excel.csv')
print(a)
```

Comment: I tried this way too, but I still run into the previous problem

Comment: don't post images of text, hard to search text in an image

Answer (score 1):

**Two problems:**

1. Please rename your python file from `pandas` to another one.
2. Modify the `Desctop\execl.csv` to `Desktop\execl.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an typo in your code.

```
a = pd.read_csv('Desctop\excel.csv')
```

Try changing the `Desctop` to `Desktop`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your path is wrong. Please try :

```
pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\win_10\\Desktop\excel.csv')
```

Comment: I tried this way too, but I still run into the previous problem –

Answer (score 0):

you have a spelling mistake, you wrote "Desctop".

if that doesn't help the path could be the problem. i also have a folder on my desktop as an example and the path looks like this.

[image]

Comment: I tried this way too, but I still run into the previous problem –

Comment: did you use the path I gave above? because you certainly have a different path.

Comment: No, I corrected the mistake and replaced it with my own

Comment: did you install the pandas library manually ?

Comment: do you use Visual Studio Code with Anaconda Navigator ? if yes i adapt my solution.

Comment: I only use visual studio code
Thank you for your help

Comment: you can install Anaconda Navigator and run VS studio with it. Anaconda is like a GUI you can easily manage packages without install it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be in your pandas installation. I would suggest you to change to your desired environment manually and then run the python script.

If it did not work, then I would suggest you to reinstall your pandas package, or create a new environment.